# Why does Inheritance polymorphism works depending on how we import in python

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, python-module

Consider these three files:

base.py

```
class Base():
    def method(self):
        print('Base Class')

object = Base()
```

main.py

```
from base import object

def main():
    object.method()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

test.py

```
import main
import base

class Derived(base.Base):
    def method(self):
        print('Derived Class')

base.object = Derived()

main.main()
```

I would expect that launching test.py will invoke the method() function of derived class but it is not.

```
$ python3.8 test.py
Base Class
```

But it works if I change the way I import object in main.py

new main.py

```
import base

def main():
    base.object.method()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

new output:

```
$ python3.8 test.py
Derived Class
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: because they are different object.

In the first case: When you import `main`, you are creating object, which I call it `main_object`. Then you are importing base, which will create `base_object`. Those object are not the same(you can use `id` to check).

In the second case: You are referencing to the same object, thus it will produce the predicted result.
try the following:

base.py

```
from base import obj
print(f"object from main has id = {id(obj)}")
def main():
    obj.method()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

main.py

```
from base import obj
print(f"object from main has id = {id(obj)}")
def main():
    obj.method()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

test.py

```
import base

import main

class Derived(base.Base):
    def method(self):
        print('Derived Class')
base.obj = Derived()
print(f"base.obj in test.py has id = {id(base.obj)}")

main.main()
```

Also, `object` is a key word in python. It's better to use different name for variables for example obj.

Comment: just noticing that "object" is not a keyword, it is the name of a builtin - there is nothing in the rules of the language preventing its reuse, but common sense. Which means, indeed, its usage as variable name should be avoided, nonetheless.